# Selecting multiple elements in jsoup

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

Is it possible in Jsoup to select multiple elements just with one query, to be more clear here is the image of the websites' structure:
[image]
so I want only the content inside these two elements, is it possible to do it with one query :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this -

```
Elements els = doc.select(".ingress,.body-text");
```

Now `els.text()` contains the whole content of those two elements.